# Image from PDF/1A is corrupt

Tags: java, pdfbox

```
PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(pdfDokument);
for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++pageIndex) {
var bim = ConvertPdfToImageUtil.pageConvertToImage(document.getPage(pageIndex), 300, ImageType.RGB);
      ImageIO.write(bim, "png", new File(  "test.png"));

public static BufferedImage pageConvertToImage(PDPage page, int dpi, ImageType imageType) throws IOException {

        try (PDDocument document = new PDDocument()) {
            document.addPage(page);
            PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            document.close();
            return renderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, dpi, imageType);
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpLQH.png)}

What is the problem with loading the pdf-a and converting it to a BufferedImage?

Comment: Also make sure you're using a recent PDFBox version, e.g. 2.0.30. If it still doesn't work, please create a new question and share your PDF.